# Python - How to change values in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I had to do a "gas factory" ! to change some values of my list of tuples:

I would like to transform this list:

```
gridDiagPosL=[[(t, t), (t, 0, 2*pi)],
 [(t, -2/3*pi + t), (t, 2/3*pi, 2*pi)],
 [(t, -4/3*pi + t), (t, 4/3*pi, 2*pi)],
 [(t, 2/3*pi + t), (t, 0, 4/3*pi)],
 [(t, 4/3*pi + t), (t, 0, 2/3*pi)]]
```

into this list :

```
gridDiagNegL=[[(t, 2*pi - t), (t, 0, 2*pi)],
 [(t, 8/3*pi - t), (t, 2/3*pi, 2*pi)],
 [(t, 10/3*pi - t), (t, 4/3*pi, 2*pi)],
 [(t, 4/3*pi - t), (t, 0, 4/3*pi)],
 [(t, 2/3*pi - t), (t, 0, 2/3*pi)]]
```

below my "gaz factory" :

```
gridDiagNegL=[]
for diag in gridDiagPosL :
    diagL=[]
    for tupl in diag :
        diagL.append(list(tupl))        
    newValue=- diagL[0][1]+2*pi
    #print('newValue : ',newValue)
    diagL[0][1]=newValue
    diagT=[]
    for listElem in diagL :
        diagT.append(tuple(listElem))     
    gridDiagNegL.append(diagT)
```

Is there a more elegant  and above all simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way of writing your function is this:

```
def gaz_factory(grid_list):
    ret = []
    for l in grid_list:
        tuple_x, tuple_y = l[0], l[1]
        new_value = -tuple_x[1] + 2 * pi
        new_list  = [(tuple_x[0], new_value), tuple_y]
        ret.append(new_list)
        
    return ret
```

It is not necessary to convert the tuples to lists, especially in the case of the second tuple in each list since that one is not modified. Since there's always two tuples, it's also more readable to assign them directly with indices instead of using a for loop.

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) we can also do it in one line:

```
def gaz_factory(grid_list):
    return [[(lst[0][0], -lst[0][1] + 2 * pi), lst[1]] for lst in grid_list]
```

Comment: very elegant your gaz_factory using list comprehensions, this solution is the one I prefer, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the tuples you are interested in inside a list comprehension with something like:

```
for [(a1, a2), b] in gridDiagPosL
```

Which will give you `a1` and `a2` corresponding to the two values of the first tuple in each list along with `b` the entire second tuple. This will allow you to create the new tuples easily:

```
t = 5     # assuming some constant
pi = 3.14

gridDiagPosL = [
 [(t, t), (t, 0, 2*pi)],
 [(t, -2/3*pi + t), (t, 2/3*pi, 2*pi)],
 [(t, -4/3*pi + t), (t, 4/3*pi, 2*pi)],
 [(t, 2/3*pi + t), (t, 0, 4/3*pi)],
 [(t, 4/3*pi + t), (t, 0, 2/3*pi)]
]

gridDiagNegL = [[(a1, -a2 + 2 * pi), b]  for [(a1, a2), b] in gridDiagPosL]
```

Comment: this one is very good too

Answer (score 0):

```
from cmath import pi
# t represents time
t = 0
gridDiagPosL = [
    [(t, t), (t, 0, 2*pi)], 
    [(t, -2/3*pi + t), (t, 2/3*pi, 2*pi)],  
    [(t, -4/3*pi + t), (t, 4/3*pi, 2*pi)],
    [(t, 2/3*pi + t), (t, 0, 4/3*pi)],
    [(t, 4/3*pi + t), (t, 0, 2/3*pi)]
    ]
# Transform the coordinates  
gridDiagNegL = [ (t, 2*pi - first, *rest)  
                 for diag in gridDiagPosL  
                 for (first, *rest) in diag]
# Increment time   
t += 0.1
# Transform coordinates at new time t
gridDiagNegL = [ (t, 2*pi - first, *rest)
                 for diag in gridDiagPosL   
                 for (first, *rest) in diag]
```

Comment: This seems to have some syntax errors.

Comment: sorry , I did not focus on syntax errors .
you can use :
gridDiagNegL = [ (t, 2*pi - first, *rest)
                 for diag in gridDiagPosL   
                 for (first, *rest) in diag]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).